# Code for resetting the counter for textboxes inserted in the word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox

I have a code that copies the bold text from textbox to the column 2 of the selected table. However
this code is not identifying the textboxes in a sequential manner and is copying the text from the textbox that was inserted first in the document and so on. This creates problem when the textboxes are not inserted sequentially. For example, if textbox 2 was inserted above textbox 1 in the document then the text from textbox 2 will be copied first in the table.

How can I reset the sequence of all textboxes so that the text is always copied from the first textbox to the last?

```
'This code copies bold text from the textboxes and insert into the column 2 of the selected table
Sub Copy_text_from_textbox_into_table()
Dim nNumber As Integer
Dim strText As String
Dim i As Long
Dim doc As Document
Dim tbl As Table
Dim rng As Range
Dim shp As Shape

Set doc = ActiveDocument
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1)

      i = 0

With doc
    For Each shp In .Shapes

        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then


        Set rng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
            With rng.Find
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Execute
                strText = rng.Text
            End With
            i = i + 1
            With tbl.Cell(Row:=i + 1, Column:=2).Range
                .Delete
                .InsertAfter Text:=strText
            End With

        Else
            MsgBox ("There is no textbox.")
                     End If
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're dealing with is the position in which the textboxes are *anchored*. This is the place in the document's text flow where the Shape is managed. If you were to look at the underlying XML you could see how this works (but that's not necessary for understanding what's happening). In order to see these anchors, go to File/Options/Display and activate "Object anchors" in the section "Always show these formatting marks on the screen". (Note: these do not print out; another term for them is "non-printing characters".)

[image]

Generally, when the user inserts a text box, it will anchor to the paragraph in which the selection is located. If the text box is then dragged, the anchor will move, unless it's been explicitly "locked" in position. When code inserts a text box, it will anchor to the `Range` specified by the `Anchor` parameter; if that's not set, it's a bit of a lottery.

When Word runs through the `Shapes` collection it follows the contiguous text in the document, picking up the `Shapes` in the order of the anchors, no matter where the object might appear on the page.

A complete solution to this very complex requirment goes beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. The following illustrates the basics about what's involved and how it can be approached.

**A simple approach**

An approach to solving this would be to loop the `Shapes`, adding each object to an array or collection. Check the vertical / horizontal positions of each object in the array (or collection), relative to the page margins. Then sort the array/collection according to this information. Finally, go through the sorted array/collection and assign the content to the table.

Doing this is further complicated by the fact that `Shape` positions can be relative to the anchor point, to a margin or to a page.

The following code shows a possible approach to getting the text boxes in the correct order (top-to-bottom) as they appear on a page.

For the sake of clarity, the step of writing the content to a table has been left out, but a comment is inserted at the point this would take place.

**The code**

The code performs three `For`loops. The first loops all `Shapes` in the document and tests whether each is a text box. If it is, the required properties are written to a user-defined `Type`, then the `Type` is assigned to an array. This is done for reasons of efficiency: looping an array of a `Type` is faster than addressing each `Shape` object again, in a later loop.

Note also, before each iteration, the `Shape` is explicitly set to be positioned relative to the page, rather than anything else. This means that the text boxes will not move on the page with the text. If this is required, another level of complexity needs to be added to ascertain how each text box is positioned, relatively, and calculate the position relative to the page based on that. (Or, it might be possible to change the setting back, but that would need to be tested to make sure the text boxes do not move. In any case, such a level of complexity goes beyond the scope of this question.)

Since we need both the `Shape` object (or a way to identify that object) and its positional information, a multi-dimensional array is needed. The number of elements (TextBoxes) is unknown when the code starts, so the array needs to be dimensioned during run-time. But `Redim Preserve` can only change the last dimension, so is not suited to this purpose. Therefore, the information cannot be assigned directly to the multi-dimensional array, which is why it's first assigned to an array of the user-defined `Type`, which carries all the information.

After dimensioning the array, the positional information is assigned to it from the array of the `Type`, along with an index value. At the same time, a third array, with the index value and the name of the `Shape` is populated.

The reason for the third array is that `WordBasic.SortArray` is used to sort the array by the `Top` position of the `Shapes` on the page. This coerces all elements into the same data type, meaning the string value of the `Shape.Name` is not retained.

Finally, the code loops the sorted array, which is now in ascending order of each text box on the page.§

```
Public Type DocShapes
    shpName As String
    top As Double
    left As Double
End Type

Sub GetTextBoxPositionalOrder()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim shp As Word.Shape
    Dim aShapes() As Variant
    Dim counter As Long, i As Long
    Dim shpType As DocShapes
    Dim shpTypes() As DocShapes
    Dim shpIndex() As Variant

    counter = 0
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    For Each shp In doc.Shapes
        'Count the shapes to dimension the array and
        'assign to user-defined Type
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
            shp.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
            shp.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
            shpType.shpName = shp.Name
            shpType.left = shp.left
            shpType.top = shp.top
            ReDim Preserve shpTypes(counter)
            shpTypes(counter) = shpType
            counter = counter + 1
         End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve aShapes(counter - 1, 2)
    ReDim Preserve shpIndex(counter - 1, 1)

    For i = LBound(shpTypes) To UBound(shpTypes)
        shpIndex(i, 0) = i + 1
        shpIndex(i, 1) = shpTypes(i).shpName
        aShapes(i, 2) = i 'corresponds to the index
        aShapes(i, 0) = shpTypes(i).top
        aShapes(i, 1) = shpTypes(i).left
    Next
    WordBasic.SortArray aShapes, 0, 0, UBound(aShapes), 0, 0
    For i = LBound(aShapes) To UBound(aShapes)
'''Write the text box content to the table at this point
        Debug.Print shpIndex(aShapes(i, 2), 1), aShapes(i, 0), aShapes(i, 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

§ Note that this code works for a one-page document. If you need to handle text boxes on multiple pages, then an added dimension is required: on which page each `Shape` is located. Then the text box information would first need to be sorted by page, and then by position on each page. Or set it up to work with one page's `Shapes` at a time.

It would also be possible to use a different sort algorithm - there are a lot out there. I used `WordBasic.SortArray` because 1) it's built-in and 2) I couldn't take the time to research various sort algorithms.

Comment: Thank you. I tried multiple times on a single page document but the textboxes are not getting sorted. The complete code is attached. Not sure what I am doing wrong. The code I used is the same as suggested and inserted the code for copying the text at the point indicated.

Comment: @Quantmodels It's not possible to "attach" code to a SO comment (or anything else). Note that you have never provided a [mcve] so that others can only *guess* what you're working with. I tested multiple times before posting. Without more detailed information on your part for reproducing the problem there's not much anyone can do... But you should test *without* the copying code, first, to make sure the basics are working...

Comment: ...you should also research Sort algorithms. My answer is not a "copy and use in your code as it stands", solution - that's simply not possible given the complexity of the topic. I just describe what's involved and how to go about creating a solution customized for one's specific needs, @Quantmodels.

Comment: Sure Thanks I will try